# What does it mean for an operation to be on the set of integers?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have to decide which of many given operations are on the set of integers. Ex($n*m=m$, $n*m=5$, and $n*m=m+m$) with $*$ meaning the operation. Does on the set of integers mean what $m$ and $n$ can be, or that the result of the operation will always be an integer?

Comment: It typically means both: $m$ and $n$ have to be integers, and the result must also be an integer.

Comment: It typically means what $n$ and $m$ (the inputs) can be. The integers may or may not be closed with respect to a given operation. If they are, then the result is always an integer as well.